# group by on one column, but select multiple

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL and I would like to ask how is it possible to transform a table like that:

```
|id |value|category|
|---|-----|--------|
| 1 |  10 |    A   |
| 2 |  90 |    A   |
| 3 |  80 |    B   |
| 4 |  20 |    B   |
```

in a table like that:

```
|id |value|category|
|---|-----|--------|
| 1 |  10 |    A   |
| 4 |  20 |    B   |
```

For each category I keep a minimum value of a category and corresponding to this value id.
I've tried a request like this, but of course it doesn't work:

```
SELECT id, MIN(value), category 
FROM table 
GROUP BY category
```

I would like to ask what will be the correct request.
I've already search in internet, but didn't found a proper response.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (category) t.*
from t
order by category, value;
```